# How can I get relative importance of attributes for my regression using SVM tune

Tags: r, svm, prediction

I'm doing prediction using SVM tune in R.Here is the code I'm using

```
  tuneResult1 <- tune(svm, demand ~ .,  data = train,
                  ranges = list(epsilon = seq(0,0.2,0.01), cost = 2^(2:9)))
```

I need to find the relative importance of independent variables used in my SVM model. Can you expert please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here you go](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/variable-importance-from-svm). Happy reading

Comment: Can I get some R code please to estimate the influence?

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave you? There is a brilliant paper in there about feature selection. You can figure the code out yourself. It is bad practice to ask for code (No, SO is not a code writing service)  when you show no effort of solving it yourself, or when you don't include reproducible examples.

Comment: I went to the link you shared.I found that it is referring some documents to read.Trust me I prefer to understand the thing first & then write the code by myself.But currently I'm under high work pressure & not getting a small time to read anything.I have to estimate the influence as early as possible.So I'm requesting here. If you can able to share with me some code to estimate the influence then it will be very helpful for me.